# 仮想通貨のマイニングは行っていないにもかかわらず、ポリシーに違反となる。

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

仮想通貨のマイニングは行っていないにもかかわらず、ポリシーに違反し、プロジェクトが停止してしまっており、この状況に困っています。

Compute EngineにPostgreSQLを構築し、そこにApp Engineにデプロイしたアプリケーションからアクセスしてデータの読み書きを行っているだけなのに、ポリシー違反が発生しています。一点だけ気になっているのは、ユーザ情報のパスワードをハッシュ化してやりとりしているため、それが影響しているかもしれません。

また、Google Cloud Platformは無料版を使用しており、テクニカルサポートが利用できません。どのような対応が必要か教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

個人の経験を話すと、Google Cloud 環境ではありませんが、とある VPS の利用時に設定が甘い事が原因で不正なプログラム (恐らくマイニング系) を仕込まれたケースがあります。

該当のサーバはゲームのマルチプレイを行うためのプログラムを動作させており、IP アドレスを知る人も数人に限られていました。

様子がおかしいことに気づいたのは、事前にサーバのモニタリングを行うよう設定していたからで、ネットワークトラフィックやリソース使用率が想定よりも上がっていたからです。

自分が遭遇した事例とよく似た記事:

[I Got Hacked!](https://www.flat-planet.net/?p=601)

---

以下の記事も参考になるかと思います。

[侵害されたクラウドインスタンスの多くで暗号資産マイニング--グーグルのレポートで明らかに | ZDNET Japan](https://japan.zdnet.com/article/35180066/)

> Google Cloud Platform（GCP）で実行されているセキュリティ設定の甘いクラウドインスタンスは、侵害後すぐに暗号資産（仮想通貨）マイニングマルウェアに感染させられていることが分かった。
> (中略)
> また多くの場合、インスタンスを侵害した後の攻撃者の行動は非常に素早く、わずかな時間で暗号資産マイニングマルウェアをインストールしていることも分かった。

Googleによるブログ、ドキュメント:

- [不正なコイン マイニング、ランサムウェア、APT の標的はクラウド ユーザー: Google サイバーセキュリティ対応チームの Threat Horizons レポート創刊号より](https://cloud.google.com/blog/ja/products/identity-security/coin-mining-ransomware-apts-target-cloud-gcat-report)
- [暗号通貨マイニング攻撃に対する保護のベスト プラクティス](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/bps-for-protecting-against-crytocurrency-attacks?hl=ja)

Comment: アドバイスいただきありがとうございます。サーバのセキュリティ対策が不十分だった可能性があり、それが原因かもしれません。
DBのリッスンが全IPから受け取れるように設定していたので・・・

Answer (score 2):

一般的な話にはなりますが、まず、ふつうプロジェクトが停止される前に警告がメールされています。警告時点であればそのメールから異議申し立てページに遷移できたはずです。

また、たとえば脆弱性を突かれたとか秘匿情報が漏れていたとかいった理由で、ご自身の把握されていない部分でクリプトマイニングが行われてしまっていた可能性もあります。リソースやログを確認してみてください。

パスワード文字列をそのまま保存せずハッシュ化して保存することはごく一般的に行われていることなので、そこだけが理由でクリプトマイニングと判定される可能性は低そうです。何か他の兆候があったのではないかと推測します（あくまで推測ですが……）。

質問者さんのプロジェクトで本当にクリプトマイニングが行われていない場合、Google と会話する以外にできることはあまり無いように思います。警告メールから辿れる申し立てページを確認してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。 
パスワードのハッシュ化には問題がなさそうでうね。

申し立てページには遷移できるので異議申し立てしてみます。